# Azure Release Pipeline - Variable for 'Triggered' Branch Name

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

So I have been working off of master for a while, and just recently added a 'release' branch that I will be working off of from now on.

In my Release Pipeline I have a PowerShell script that sets a custom variable using predefined variables.

```
$branchName = $Env:BUILD_SOURCEBRANCHNAME
$buildNumber = $Env:BUILD_BUILDNUMBER
$release = $branchName + "." + $buildNumber.ToString()

$pipeline.variables.NameVar.value = $release
```

If I push code to my release branch, this script will run at the end of my pipeline, and the variable should be changed to `release.xxxx`, but it is changed to `master.xxxx`.

Is there a reason the build variable `build.sourcebranchname` does not return my release branch name, and instead returns master? The `build.buildnumber` variable returns the correct value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I figured out my issue. After adding the new release branch, I needed to edit my build pipeline to setup multiple branches. Basically following [this doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/build/ci-build-git?view=azure-devops&tabs=classic) from Microsoft.

Adding `release/*` as a branch filter allowed the build pipeline to build on the release branch, and not just the master branch. From that point on, when I used the build variables in my release pipeline, they all returned the proper value.

Answer (score 1):

Try to go to `Get sources` and check whether you select the correct branch.

[image]

I've tested your script and it returned expected result:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for that. Seeing where you changed the default branch actually put me on the right track. Instead of changing the default branch (I want to keep that as master), I was able to add a branch filter for my new branch which resolved my issue.